# Jackson Json Crypto with temporal workflow - Decryption of data while retrieval not happening

Tags: encryption, jackson-modules, temporal-workflow

I am using **temporal workflows** to manage states and currently data is being saved as plain text which i want to save the data in encrypted format.

For that, I am using **Jackson Json Crypto module** for encryption. Encryption is working fine and data is getting saved in encrypted form but **while deserialising, data is not getting back converted to actual data**. I believe @Encrypt annotation which is used and defined on the field is not getting triggered. I have download the decompiled library code as well and tried debugging, where i found deserialising module constructors are getting called initially but later the @Override deserialise function is not getting triggered and the encrypted json output is getting returned as it is and getting mapped to the field.

Anyone any idea, how annotation works while serialising, deserialising?
Also, @Encrypt annotation will work first or object mapper will map the data to pojo?

Thanks in advance

Code snippets

//Configuration and registering crypto module in object mapper

`EncryptionService encryptionService = new EncryptionService(jacksonObjectMapper, new PasswordCryptoContext("Password1")); jacksonObjectMapper.registerModule(new CryptoModule().addEncryptionService(encryptionService));`

//Encrypt annotation on field

`@JsonProperty("order_id") @Encrypt private String orderId;`

// Encrypted Data Output

```
"order_id": {        "salt": "Bf53VhtWMF95Cp7wLb8EJ9tRfIc=",        "iv": "X83bkmfrvHk4SGCTJ+zx/g==",        "value": "L8VEVKkEp0j7KG0cG2IFjHdNmMKcIxnLIb0+fiNqnDr2AXRrFgwJaaR6E8f5n7DI"      }
```

While deserialising

//Expecting

"order_id":"abcd" // actual string

//Output

```
"order_id": {        "salt": "Bf53VhtWMF95Cp7wLb8EJ9tRfIc=",        "iv": "X83bkmfrvHk4SGCTJ+zx/g==",        "value": "L8VEVKkEp0j7KG0cG2IFjHdNmMKcIxnLIb0+fiNqnDr2AXRrFgwJaaR6E8f5n7DI"      }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your issue is related Jackson's annotation. More likely related to the way you register your Jackson `ObjectMapper` to your Temporal Client's `PayloadConverter`.

I suggest you get a look at [this sample](https://github.com/temporalio/samples-java/blob/main/core/src/main/java/io/temporal/samples/payloadconverter) from the Temporal's Java SDK Samples official repository, which does exactly what you are trying to do.

The important thing to observe in that sample is:

1. The Jackson's `ObjectMapper` must be wrapped into a `JacksonJsonPayloadConverter` object, like this:

```
    PayloadConverter encryptingPayloadConverter =
            new JacksonJsonPayloadConverter(objectMapper);
```

2. A new `DataConverter` must be created, that includes your custom `PayloadConverter`:

```
    DataConverter customDataConverter =
            DefaultDataConverter.newDefaultInstance()
                .withPayloadConverterOverrides(encryptingPayloadConverter)
```

3. Your custom `DataConverter` must be attached to your Temporal `Client`:

```
    WorkflowClient.newInstance(
            service,
            WorkflowClientOptions.newBuilder()
                .setDataConverter(customDataConverter)
                .build());
```

Make sure to do this for all Temporal Clients that will manipulate that type of payloads (eg. client code, Workflow workers, and Activity workers).

Also, notice that even though using the Jackson Json Crypto module might be a bit easier to start with, it is alternatively possible to implement encryption using a `PayloadCodec` (see [this sample](https://github.com/temporalio/samples-java/tree/main/core/src/main/java/io/temporal/samples/encryptedpayloads)). `PayloadCodec` will turn out easier to use in cross-language scenarios, and allow encoding Temporal Failure' messages and stack traces.

Comment: Hi James, Thanks for replying. These configurations that you have suggested are already in place. After registering the crypto module to object mapper, that object mapper is being getting set in JacksonJsonPayload converter and is getting passed in data converter also. The issue is not due to configuration as encrypt is working fine whereas only at time of decryption, I am facing issues. Seems, some rule being violated due to which deserialise of crypto module is not getting triggered

Comment: Are you sure you are setting this custom `DataConverter` on all `Client` you create, including your own client code, your workflow workers and your activity workers? Actually, who (as in which code) in your app is encoding those payloads, and who is trying to decode them?

Comment: Also make sure that every place where you expect these payloads use the proper class (eg. `MyOrderDTO`), not some generic object (eg. `Object`, `ObjectNode` `JSONObject`, etc).

Comment: In the output you provided, we see that after deserialization, the `order_id` field (rather than `orderId`) contains some "encrypted" object (rather than a `String`). That means that the object you have at that point is not an instance of the class you are expecting, but some other class that carry the JSON document itself. That's incorrect.